# What is difference between using #define max 100 then stack[max] and directly using stack[100] in C?

Tags: arrays, c, stack

So I was studying about implementing stack using an array in C and one common thing I noticed in quite a few sample codes was the use of #define

```
#define MAX 100

int stack[MAX];
```

my question is what advantage does this offer over the direct method

```
int stack[100];
```

I'm assuming the define method might offer some sort of performance boost. Or do both methods produce identical results?

Comment: The first is preferred: without "magic numbers" in the code. There is NO performance boost. They produce identical results but the first is easier to maintain. Consider that you also use another unrelated `100` elsewhere in the code, but you want to change one to `50`. Apart from needing to look at all the loops etc which use `100`, *which* of them should be changed to `50`? When using a `#define` you'll only need to change a single definition.

Comment: @mkrieger1 ok so basically in C, #define is used to define a true constant that can't be altered at any point in the code, did I get it right?

Comment: It is simple text substitution.

Comment: Shouldn't `#define` be explained in any introduction to C way before trying to implement non-trivial data structures? Starting with data structures before knowing the basics of the language is a bad idea.

Comment: You can also use anynoumous enumeration: `enum { MAX = 100 };`. Advantages over macros are better debugging and better scoping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They produce identical results, by definition.  Macros in C (and C++) are simple text substitution, where you see the macro the compiler will substitute whatever you have `#define`d the macro to be.  With a few exceptions such as inside a string literal.

The reason why you want to use a macro is not for performance but for documentation and ease of editing.  You can give the macro a meaningful name so you know what it's being used for.  You won't confuse the macro for any other `100` constants you may have in your code.  And if you ever need to change it, you change it in a single place and all the places you use it will be updated automatically.